# Rxjs execute the handler only once

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have two observable that I am listening too with the merge operator when one of them is fire, or both I need to execute the handler only once, How can I do this with rx?

```
var source1 = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);

var source2 = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);

var source = Rx.Observable.merge(
    source1,
    source2)
    .subscribe(() => console.log('This needs to run only once and not kill the stream'))
```

Comment: Try `.take(1)`.

Comment: Try with `.first()`

Comment: `take(1)`, `first()`, `single()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345969/angular-2-using-rxjs-take1-vs-first/42346203#42346203. Maybe also `forkJoin` but it depends on what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector function of multicast

> Optional selector function that can use the multicasted source stream as many times as needed, without causing multiple subscriptions to the source stream. Subscribers to the given source will receive all notifications of the source from the time of the subscription forward.

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-multicast

```
 function factory() {
   return new Rx.Subject();
 }

 source.multicast(factory, function(shared) {
   return shared.take(1).do(x=>console.log(x)).concat(shared);
 })
 .subscribe();
```

Comment: I can't take 1 I need to continue the stream and if two of them pushes value at the same time to run the handler only once.

Comment: it will continue the stream. see the concat with original stream. please try.