# Observable subscribe called multiple times?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable

I have the following `Observable`:

**dataService.ts**

```
findMessages(chatItem: any): Observable<any[]> {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
        this.firebaseDataService.findMessages(chatItem).subscribe((firebaseItems: any[]) => {
              // do something
                observer.next(somedata);
        });
    });
}
```

which calls this function:

**firebaseDataService.ts**

```
findMessages(chatItem: any): Observable<any[]> { // populates the firelist
    return this.af.database.list('/message/', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'negativtimestamp'
        }
    }).map(items => {
        const filtered = items.filter(
            item => ((item.memberId1 === chatItem.memberId1 && item.memberId2 === chatItem.memberId2)
                || (item.memberId1 === chatItem.memberId2 && item.memberId2 === chatItem.memberId1))
        );
        return filtered;
    });
}
```

The `dataService.findMessages(chatItem)` function is only ever called once.

This observes the firebase list. So if any items on the list change, this `Observable` is fired.

**Problem**

If the function is accessed, or one item is added to the list, the Observer is fired as expected, but the `// do something` line is called multiple times. I would only expect it to be called once.

**Question**

- Is there a way to enforce that it's only called once?
- Or once it's called for the first time, to break out of the
  `subscribe`?
- Or, is my code completely wrong?

Any advise appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831736/rxjs-execute-the-handler-only-once

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the comment. I do however get, `[ts] Property 'multicast' does not exist on type 'Observable<any[]>'.`. I may need to investigate a little further.

Comment: => resolved by: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/multicast';`

Comment: I am not sure how to construct the parameters for `multicast(parameters)`. It looks like I need a `Rx.Subject`, but what is this? How do i get this?

Comment: use take(1) if you need to have only one emition

Comment: Hi Julia, thank you for your comment.  Where do I use `take(1)`? On the `Observable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but the // do something line is called multiple times

It is called in the callback passed to `this.firebaseDataService.findMessages(chatItem).subscribe`. The `subscribe` function will fire whenever there is a new item. If you only want to take one item you can use the `take` operator

## More

Docs on `take` : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/take.md