# AngularJS - ValueChanges only first ime

Tags: angular

I am working on AngularJS PWA App (Have form in my registration component)

**Form have 3 step:**

**STEP 1**

- First Name
- Last Name
- Email
- Password
- Phone Number

**STEP 2**

- example
- example

**STEP 3**

- example
- example

**When my user will finish first step I have radio buttons:**

```
 <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="step2" formControlName="step2" value="1"> Fortsæt</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="step2" formControlName="step2" value="2"> Ring mig op</label>
 </div>
```

**Code:**

```
this.rForm.get('step2').valueChanges.subscribe(
    (step2) => {
        // here I have user registration width angularfire2
        this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {
    }
});
```

when user click one of radio button, this code will register user in firebase, but if user will click again second radio button, code will try register user again and I am getting error in my console (email alaready exits..).

what is solution for this? I want register user only first time touch to radio button. I am not using here submit, because I have another fields and steps. I want register user only first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `first` or `take` operator

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
```

```
this.rForm.get('step2').valueChanges.first().subscribe(

this.rForm.get('step2').valueChanges.take(1).subscribe(
```

See also [Angular 2 using RxJS - take(1) vs first()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345969/angular-2-using-rxjs-take1-vs-first)

Comment: Getting error when .valueChanges.first.subscribe:    roperty 'subscribe' does not exist on type '{ <T, S extends T>(this: Observable<T>, predicate: (value: T, index: number, source: Observable<T...'.

Comment: Sorry, `first` is a function, not a property. I forgot `()`

Comment: this works, but now I have small problem: first time click step2 = 1 second time click step2=2 so if step2=2 I am showing another form inputs, but width this code second click not working anymore

Comment: Sorry, I don't seem to understand your last comment. Perhaps you need to call `this.rForm.get('step2').valueChanges.subscribe(...` again after a click.