# first() operand does not publish after a second call inside a function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I don't understand why this does not work but the alternatives below do.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  id = 0;
  obs = new Subject();

  changeValue() {
    this.fakeApiCall(this.id++)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(this.obs);
  }

  fakeApiCall(id: number) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      console.log('called with id ' + id);
      observer.next({ items: [id, Math.random()] });
    });
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>
    <div *ngIf="(obs | async) as v">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of v.items">
                {{ item }}
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of v.items">
                {{ item }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="(obs | async) as v">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of v.items">
                {{ item }}
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of v.items">
                {{ item }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <button (click)="changeValue()">increase counter</button>
</h1>
```

When I'm clicking the "increase counter" button, it first gets values, but not afterward, while these alternatives work just fine:

```
changeValue() {
    this.fakeApiCall(this.id++)
      .subscribe(this.obs)
      .unsubscribe();
  }
```

or

```
changeValue() {
    this.fakeApiCall(this.id++)
      .pipe(take(2)) // NOTES: if I write take(1), it has the same effect.
      .subscribe(this.obs);
  }
```

I am confused is this a bug or what's really going on here?

EDIT: if you want stackblitz url, here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-28eyiy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, the problem is in the way you're subscribing `Subject` with `subscribe(this.obs)`.

When you use `subscribe(this.obs)` you're passing all notifications to your `Subject` instance. This means `next`, `complete` and `error` notifications. And here's the problem, `first()` will complete the chain after the first emission (btw see [Angular 2 using RxJS - take(1) vs first()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345969/angular-2-using-rxjs-take1-vs-first)) which means it'll pass one `next` and one `complete` notification. When `Subject` receives a `complete` notification its stopped and will never ever re-emit anything even when you subscribe it again to a different chain (this is a part of ["The Observable Contract"](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html)).

So if you want to use the same `Subject` in multiple subscriptions where you know they'll complete you can pass only the `next` notification and nothing more (`Subject` will stay active):

```
.subscribe(v => this.obs.next(v));
```

Comment: ahh! good catch, never thought about the complete notification. nice job buddy and thank you!