# Detect variable changes into localStorage angular 8

Tags: html, angular

I have this funcion on the component calls navbar:

```
getAddUsuario(){
if(window.localStorage.getItem('addUsuario') == 'false'){
  window.localStorage.setItem('addUsuario','true');

}else{
  window.localStorage.setItem('addUsuario','false');      
}
return window.localStorage.getItem('addUsuario');
```

So, when i click the variable addUsuario change to false if is true and to true if is false.

The problem is i wqant to detect that changes from another component and pass it into HTML. if is true take a div class and if is false take another div class.

I tried with addEventlistener but doesnt work.

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking

Comment: Hi, tell me what i dont understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the functions to a singleton service and monitor the value using observables. Try the following

Shared service

```js
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';  // <-- included 'Observable' here - with capital 'O'

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  private addUsuarioSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('false');
  public addUsuario$ = this.addUsuarioSource.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    this.addUsuario$.subscribe(status => window.localStorage.setItem('addUsuario', status));   // <-- changed 'userStatus' to 'status'
  }

  getAddUsuario(): Observable<string> {   // <-- capital 'O' instead of small 'o'
    let userStatus = window.localStorage.getItem('addUsuario');
    userStatus = (userStatus === 'false' || userStatus == null) ? 'true' : 'false';
    this.addUsuarioSource.next(userStatus);
    return this.addUsuario$;
  }
}
```

Navbar component

```js
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit() {
  subscription: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.subscription = this.sharedService.getAddUsuario().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(status => {
      // this callback will be called only once due to `pipe(take(1))`
      // `status` variable with value 'true' or 'false' as string
    });
  }
}
```

Another component

```js
this.sharedService.addUsuario$.subscribe(status => {
  // this callback will be called each time a new user status is pushed
  // `status` variable with value 'true' or 'false' as string
})
```

I am using [`BehaviorSubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) to provide a default value. You could use Rxjs [`Subject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subject) if you do not wish to provide a default value. Explanation for `pipe(take(1))` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42346203/6513921).

Note: Storing boolean in local storage isn't a good idea. Because you can only store strings and it returns the values as strings. So you cannot do something like `*ngIf==="status"` or  `*ngIf==="!status"`. It would be `*ngIf="status === 'true'"` and `*ngIf="status === 'false'"`.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmwcdk)

Comment: I have a error with take? what i need to import? Thanks

Comment: Doesnt work. I mean when i click the variable change from true to false and if i press that button again didnt change to true.

Comment: There were some minor typos and errors in the service code. I've modified it and added relevant comments. Please check if it still doesn't work for you.

Comment: It works now, i maked the same like u. When i press click, cheking localStorage the variable change, but didnt change into html. U know why?

Comment: I've made a working Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gubjbl). There were few other tweaks required. Since we subscribe on every button press, we need to make sure the previous subscription is unsubscribed. Please see if it works for you.

Comment: What u do work, but in my child component html y have something like this: <div *ngIf="status">yes</div> <div *ngIf="!status">no</div>. And didnt work

Comment: That will not work. Because the data returned from the local storage is of the type `string`. So you need to check for conditions `*ngIf="status === 'true'"` and `*ngIf="status === 'false'"`. I've modified the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmwcdk). Storing boolean in local storage isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your typescript

create a global variable like this:

```
addUsuario:boolean;

getAddUsuario(){ 
if(window.localStorage.getItem('addUsuario') == 'false'){
window.localStorage.setItem('addUsuario','true');
//and do this one
addUsuario = true;
}else{
window.localStorage.setItem('addUsuario','false');    
addUsuario = false;  
}
return window.localStorage.getItem('addUsuario');
```

and in your HTML you can use *ngIf
for example:

```
<div *ngIf="addUsuario == true">
<!--Your div-->
</div>
<div *ngIf="addUsuario == false">
<!--your div-->
</div>
```