# Get the first item that matches a condition in Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular9

I need to get, from an observable, the first item in `payload.result` which type is `avatar`:

```
let result = this.fileService.getAvatarByUserId(2).pipe(
  map((payload: Payload<FileModel[]>) => payload.result),
  first((result: FileModel[]) => result.type == 'avatar')
);
```

But I get error that "is not assignable to type 'Observable'"

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of the following based on your needs...

filter + take(1)

```
this.fileService.getAvatarByUserId(2)
      .pipe(
        map((payload: Payload<FileModel[]>) => payload.result),
        flatMap(uploads => uploads), // Flattens the array
        filter(upload => upload.type === 'avatar'), // filters anything that's avatart
        take(1) // return only the first
    ).subscribe(
      console.log
    );
```

OR

first(predicate function) -> my preference

```
this.fileService.getAvatarByUserId(2)
      .pipe(
        map((payload: Payload<FileModel[]>) => payload.result),
        flatMap(uploads => uploads), // Flattens the array
        first(upload => upload.type === 'avatar') // returns the first positive match
    ).subscribe(
      console.log,
      console.log // this is to log an error if no match found when the subscription completes
    );
```

OR
filter + first

```
this.fileService.getAvatarByUserId(2)
      .pipe(
        map((payload: Payload<FileModel[]>) => payload.result),
        flatMap(uploads => uploads), // Flattens the array
        filter(upload => upload.type === 'avatar'), // filters anything that's avatart
        first() // returns the first value
    ).subscribe(
      console.log,
      console.log // this is to log an error if no match found when the subscription completes
    );
```

first operator can notify if the condition was not met when the subscription completes by adding the error method to the subscription -> see the subscription for the last two options (probably why i like this the most...)

see this in [action](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flatmap-and-filter-example?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

edited to add more clarity for the first operator based on  @Jonathan Stellwag comments (thank you!!!)

Comment: Take and first is not the same. If you want an error in case a condition is not happening, first is the way to go. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345969/take1-vs-first

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [filter](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/filter) and [take](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/take) operator.

```
let result = this.fileService.getFilesByUserId().pipe(
  filter(payload => payload.payload.result === 'avatar'),
  take(1)
);
```

Comment: I need to apply the condition to each result and get the first that satisfies it and not to payload. I just updated my question to clarify it ...

Comment: @MiguelMoura I updated the answer. Please add further informations if it's still not your requirement. Best case szenario to understand your question would be to provide the exact source (observable emits + type) and what you expect as a result (when + type).