# How do you make this observable-inside-an-observable work?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm building an autocomplete function that uses the user's input to filter a set of meals as they type:

```
export class MealAutocompleteComponent {

  mealCtrl = new FormControl()
  filteredMeals: Observable<Array<Meal>>
  liveMeals$: Observable<Array<Meal>>
  mealsSnapshot: Meal[]

  constructor(private mealsQuery: MealsQuery) {
    this.liveMeals$ = this.mealsQuery.all$        // <= observable (not used)
    this.mealsSnapshot= this.mealsQuery.getAll()  // <= array (used)

    // Observe the user input and trigger filtering
    this.filteredMeals = this.mealCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(null),
      map((filterTerm: string | null) => {
        let mealArr: Array<Meal> = mealsQuery.getAll() // <= I'd like to use observable instead
        return filterTerm ? this._filter(filterTerm, mealArr) : mealArr
      })
    )
  }

  private _filter(value: string, meals:Array<Meal>): Array<Meal> {
    // Method for filtering meals
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase()

    return meals.filter(meal =>
      meal.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0
    )
  }

}
```

#### How can I switch from using meals:Array to meals:Observable?

The code above all works as intended. However there are two places that we can get the overall list of `meals` from - an array `this.mealsSnapshot`, and an observable: `this.liveMeals`.

I've written the code above using the `mealsSnapshot` array. However I would prefer to use the `liveMeals$` observable since, for various reasons, it offers more flexibility (and is drawn from a state store). But I've absolutely no idea what the correct RxJS operators are to do this. The `liveMeals$` observable is an observable that returns a single array of meals.

I've tried something like this but a) it's got subscribers inside subscribes which I know is not the RxJS way and b) it doesn't work c) it looks a mess

```
    this.filteredMeals = this.mealCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(null),
      concatMap((filterTerm: string | null) => {
        this.liveMeals$.pipe(
          first()  
        ).subscribe((mealsArr:Meal) => {
          return filterTerm ? this._filter(filterTerm, mealsArr) : mealsArr
        }
        )
      })
    )
```

What would be the correct way to use `liveMeals$:Observable<Array>` rather than the `mealsSnapshot`?

Comment: I *think* you're just asking how to apply an array filter to an observable of arrays, in which case `obsOfArr.pipe(map(arr => arrFilter(arr)))` gives an observable of filtered arrays.

Comment: When writing an arrow function with a block body, one must use the `return` keyword to return.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I believe you only need to return if you're using curly brackets `{ }` - if not then the line will be the return value. And *I believe* you only need the curly brackets if you want to execute more than one line of code. @jonrsharpe - that's part of the answer although wthout either `take` or `concatMap` it doesn't get quite far enough

Comment: Yeah, but your `concatMap` callback is braced/bracketed and lacks a `return`. Since `concatMap` callbacks are projections, I assumed you forgot it.

Comment: ahh - my apologies - my code was screwed but it was so far screwed that I couldn't narrow down all the things that were wrong. So thank you for pointing that out - that would explain one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in choosing a higher order operator (`concatMap`) to switch from one observable to another. But the subscription inside isn't required. You could switch to another observable and use `map` to use your condition.

If it's used in a typeahead, you could also use `debounceTime` operator to control the number of emissions that triggers the filter.

Try the following

```js
this.filteredMeals = this.mealCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(null),
  debounceTime(300),                // <-- suspend emission if last emission was < 300ms
  concatMap((filterTerm: string | null) =>
    this.mealsQuery.all$.pipe(      // <-- or `this.liveMeals$` since they're the same
      take(1),                      // <-- take only the first value
      map(meal => filterTerm ? this._filter(filterTerm, meal) : meal)
    );
  )
);
```

---

<sup>Differences b/n `first()` and `take(1)`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42346203/6513921</sup>

Comment: That's super thank you Michael. Your code worked perfectly. I have a question though - why do you need to use either `take` or `first`. Empirically you're right - if I don't use them then the code inside the second `map` statement doesn't execute during the `valueChanges` event. But why is that - why does the `first/take` force the `all$` to emit a value?

Comment: @PeterNixey: It doesn't force the `all$` to emit a value. It makes the inner observable `this.mealsQuery.all$` to complete on it's first emission. Since you're using `concatMap`, the subsequent emissions from `valueChanges` won't be processed unless the inner subscription completes. So if the `take(1)` or `first()` isn't used, the inner observable might never complete and newer emissions from outer observable will never be used.

Comment: @PeterNixey: There are also other ways to handle it. Instead of `concatMap()` you could use the other higher order mapping operators `switchMap`, `mergeMap` or `exhaustMap`. They make sure the outer emissions are handled even if the inner observable hasn't completed yet. Each handle the outer emission differently. You could see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685990/6513921) for a very brief differences b/n them.

Comment: @PeterNixey: One more point to note: The code inside `map` would run during the `valueChanges` event regardless of `take(1)`.

Comment: all very helpful and a good prompt to try the other mappings. BTW to your last point, when it's a concatMap, removing the `take(1)` means that none of the code executes during the valueChanges event. Presumably because the concatenation of events == no event since the inner observable isn't completing. However if I use mergeMap then the code inside the inner observable does complete. Just FYI. I have to say I'm a little surprised that the inner observable completes with mergeMap (and no `take`), I wouldn't have expected that...

Comment: i.e. 
````
  mergeMap((filterTerm: string | null) =>
    console.log('inside outer observer')
    this.mealsQuery.all$.pipe(
      console.log('inside inner observer')
      map(meal => filterTerm ? this._filter(filterTerm, meal) : meal)
    );
  )
````

- on valueChange,  mergeMap prints both of the statements. concatMap prints neither of the statements

Comment: Sorry Michael - one last question. Why does this example all work even though the valueChanges observer is never subscribed to? I would have expected this to require `.subscribe()` somewhere but it works fine without it. Why is that? Thank you

Comment: Hi @PeterNixey, I'd depend on how the `this.filteredMeals` variable is used. Surely there is a subscription somewhere in the code. Without it, the there isn't a proper way to consume the notifications from the observable.

Comment: great spot - it's in the template with an `async` pipe. I kept looking at the component file and couldn't find it - but it was because it was in the template! 