# take(1) vs firstValueFrom vs observable.value

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

In my project, I use `BehaviorSubject`s as data stores to store the state of my application.

I need only the **current** value that is currently held in the `BehaviorSubject` store, and don't need to subscribe to future values that can be emitted through the behavior subject.

I found few implementations of how to do this: using `pipe(take(1))`, `firstValueFrom` and `.value`.

Do all work the same way and read the current value in the BehaviorSubject store?
What are the differences between them, if any?

```
private myStore$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

// reading only one current value using take(1):
this.myStore$.pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(value => console.log('current value = ', value));

// reading only one current value using firstValueFrom:
const value = await firstValueFrom(this.myStore$);
console.log('current value = ', value);

// reading only one current value using this.myStore$.value:
const value = this.myStore$.value;
console.log('current value = ', value);
```

Comment: Regarding operators, the classic one would be `first` vs `take(1)`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345969/take1-vs-first

Comment: Well, one of the differences is that `myStore$.value` is synchronous, you don't need any async constructs to access it. The `take(1)` variant is asynchronous but it is still using observables (recommended approach in my opinion if you want to go with async access for this value. Check Aldin's comment about `take(1)` vs `first()` and see which one best fits your requirements) and the `firstValueFrom` will give you a promise object that needs to be handled using either `await` like in your snippet, or using `then`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically using `take(1)` or `firstValueFrom` is the same because they access the value asynchronously:

```
myStore$.pipe(
  take(1)
).subscribe(value => {...});
```

`firstValueFrom` turns Observable into a Promise so you can use `async`/`await`:

```
const value = await firstValueFrom(myStore$.pipe(
  take(1)
));
```

Using `BehaviorSubject.value` to synchronously access its value is in general [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45227115/310726). It might behave unexpectedly if `BehaviorSubject` errors or when it's unsubscribed:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

const subject1 = new BehaviorSubject(1);
console.log(subject1.value);
subject1.error(new Error('broken'));
try {
  console.log(subject1.value);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}

const subject2 = new BehaviorSubject(2);
console.log(subject2.value);
subject2.unsubscribe();
try {
  console.log(subject2.value);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-npalak?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a great answer.

Comment: @marlin whats the point of using take(1) inside the firstValueFrom method, when you already get the first value while using it.

Comment: I think you're right, it should not be necessary

Comment: @martin If it is not necessary why are you not editing your example to 
const value = await firstValueFrom(myStore$);